# How can I streamline the LookUp command below?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this:

```
public HierarquiaDto Selecionar(int id) {
        var query = (from p in Context.PapelContratos
                    join g in Context.GruposCargo on new { a=p.UsuarioGrupoCargo, b=p.EmpresaId }  equals new { a=g.Sigla, b=g.EmpresaId } into pg
                    from g in pg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where p.OrigemId == id
                    select new
                    {
                        p.PaisId,
                        p.EmpresaId,
                        p.Codigo,
                        p.Nome,
                        p.PapelId,
                        OrigemId = p.OrigemId.Value,
                        p.IsPendente,
                        p.HierarquiaPapelId,
                        p.UsuarioId,
                        p.UsuarioNome,
                        p.UsuarioGrupoCargo,
                        p.UsuarioMatricula,
                        GrupoCargoNome = g.Nome
                    });

        Context.Database.CommandTimeout = 9000;
        var lookup = query.ToLookup(
            i => new { PaisId = i.PaisId, EmpresaId = i.EmpresaId, Codigo = i.Codigo, Nome = i.Nome, OrigemId = i.OrigemId },
            v => new HierarquiaUsuarioSimplesDto { PapelId = v.PapelId, HierarquiaPapelId = v.HierarquiaPapelId, Usuario = new HierarquiaUsuarioDto { Id = v.UsuarioId, Nome = v.UsuarioNome, Matricula = v.UsuarioMatricula, GrupoCargo = v.UsuarioGrupoCargo, GrupoCargoNome = v.GrupoCargoNome } }
        );

        var item = query.FirstOrDefault();

        return new HierarquiaDto
        {
            PaisId = item.PaisId,
            EmpresaId = item.EmpresaId,
            Codigo = item.Codigo,
            Nome = item.Nome,
            OrigemId = item.OrigemId,
            IsPendente = item.IsPendente,
            Usuarios = lookup.FirstOrDefault().ToList()
        };
    }
```

I am trying to create a list of type HierarchyDto, in this object I have another called HierarchyUsuarioSimplesDto and inside this I have another one that is called User HierarchyD, I did not do this code I am just trying to improve it.
I need all the users that belong to that PaisId, CompanyId, Code, Name and OriginId.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I'm learning both the technology and the operation of stackoverflow, I sincerely hoped to get help, but so far this has not happened. Thank you for your attention and apologies for any inconveniences.

Comment: The code is only narrowing it to the first found that has a matching `p.OrigemId == id`. I don't see where it filters on the other conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ToLookup` is being used in a very strange way to emulate a `group` ... `by`, so I am not positive this returns the same answer, because it really depends on how `ToLookup` will choose the member to return for `FirstOrDefault` (probably something you shouldn't depend on working). There seems to be a few cases of `FirstOrDefault` that should be `First`.

This is my attempt to use more normal LINQ to achieve the same answer:

```
var query = from p in Context.PapelContratos
            where p.OrigemId == id
            join g in Context.GruposCargo on new { a = p.UsuarioGrupoCargo, b = p.EmpresaId } equals new { a = g.Sigla, b = g.EmpresaId } into pg
            from g in pg.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { p, g } by new { p.PaisId, p.EmpresaId, p.Codigo, p.Nome, p.OrigemId } into pg_g
            select new HierarquiaDto {
                PaisId = pg_g.Key.PaisId,
                EmpresaId = pg_g.Key.EmpresaId,
                Codigo = pg_g.Key.Codigo,
                Nome = pg_g.Key.Nome,
                OrigemId = pg_g.Key.OrigemId.Value,
                IsPendente = pg_g.First().p.IsPendente,
                Usuarios = pg_g.Select(pg => new HierarquiaUsuarioSimplesDto {
                    PapelId = pg.p.PapelId,
                    HierarquiaPapelId = pg.p.HierarquiaPapelId,
                    Usuario = new HierarquiaUsuarioDto {
                        Id = pg.p.UsuarioId,
                        Nome = pg.p.UsuarioNome,
                        Matricula = pg.p.UsuarioMatricula,
                        GrupoCargo = pg.p.UsuarioGrupoCargo,
                        GrupoCargoNome = pg.g.Nome
                    }
                }).ToList()   
            };

var ans = query.FirstOrDefault();
```